# In-plane magnetic field and Dirac operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

Consider a 2D Dirac operator

$$H= p_x \sigma_x + p_y \sigma_y.$$

Now if I wanted to introduce a magnetic field in the $2D$ plane, I could do so by using a vector potential

$$ A= (0,0,B_xy-B_yx).$$

So in principle, we would have that $\operatorname{curl}(A)=(B_x,B_y,0)^t$ which is an in-plane field.

Now the question is: What is the right way to add this to the Dirac operator?

My first guess would have been

$$H_B = p_x\sigma_x+p_y \sigma_y +A_3 \sigma_3$$
where $A_3$ is the third component of the vector potential.

If this is not correct, then what would this Hamiltonian $H_B$ actually represent?

Comment: $H_B$ represents a spatially dependent mass of the Dirac fermion; such spatially dependent masses have been studied extensively in the context of graphene, where they may arise from a substrate on which the carbon monolayer is placed.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker that is very interesting. Is there an example that would introduce the spatially-varying mass term that I wrote down there in graphene?

Comment: this would be a domain wall; orient your lattice so that $B_x=0$, then you have a mass term that passes through zero along the line $x=0$; such a domain wall traps a zero-mode, a state at zero energy extended along the domain wall; in graphene the linear $x$-dependence would only hold locally, far from the domain wall the mass would saturate; in this connection, could you enlighten me on the origin of the Hamiltonian you asked about recently at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401760/spectrum-of-matrix-involving-quantum-harmonic-oscillator)?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker this operator was motivated from a paper by E.Mele and one of his students on twisted bilayer graphene that has strain in one spatial direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a particle on confined to a 2D plane, a magnetic field in that plane does not make sense. Such a field would try to force the particle off the plane. The only part of the magnetic field that can meaningfully interact with the particle is the vector component *perpendicular* to the plane. That way, the Lorentz force remains in the plane. In 2 dimensions, the magnetic field therefore does not appear as a vector quantity but as a scalar one. The magnetic field is naturally a type of thing called a *bivector*, in all dimensionalities. It is a quirk of 3D that it seems like a vector and a quirk of 2D that it seems like a scalar. But it isn't "really" either of those, which is why trying to restrict it to a plane like a normal 3D vector doesn't work.

In contrast, the vector potential $A$ *is* a true vector and when you restrict to 2D it should just lose a component. In doing so you (correctly!) lose the ability to make in-plane magnetic fields with it, since its curl is now just a scalar. You add it to the mechanical momentum to form the canonical momentum just as you normally would. $$H=(p_x+A_x)\sigma_x+(p_y+A_y)\sigma_y,$$ where the charge of the particle $q=1.$

Comment: thank you, is there any physical interpretation of the Hamiltonian I wrote down there? Also, imagine you take a 3D Dirac operator and you just do not allow for any motion in the z-direction but you still implement an in-plane magnetic field. Wouldn't this be somewhat the operator I tried to write down?

Comment: @KungYao Well, you'd need to add another term to the Hamiltonian to represent whatever force/interaction is confining the particle to the plane against the influence of $A_3=A_z$. This is purely speculation, but doesn't it stand to reason that any such term would just cancel out $A_z$? Also, $A_z$, if it *is* going to appear, should appear multiplying one of the Pauli matrices.... but we're out of those (we've already used up 2 for space and we must leave 1 for time). So no, I don't think what you've written has much physical meaning.